# override CSS nested attribute

Tags: css, nested

Simple question regarding overriding a CSS attribute that is nested.

I've tried going up to the source of this gallery style sheet to get to the base of it but I just can't seem to work my way around it.

I am simply trying to change the max-width and width of

```
body.gallery .asset.is-landscape img
```

to a new value but It seems to not work even when attributed !important

here is the CSS in question I am aiming to make make the above mentionned change to:

```
body.gallery .asset.is-landscape img, body.gallery .asset.is-square img, body.nested_gallery .asset.is-landscape img, body.nested_gallery .asset.is-square img {
    max-width: 550px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Here is the whole style sheet which i thoroughly tried changing the elements I thought could affect the nested body gallery, but without success. Bare in mind I am obviously not expert, this might be something easy to resolve.

```
/*
------------------------------------------------------------------
Gallery Styles
------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
html.is-changing body.gallery .main, html.is-changing body.nested_gallery .main {
  transform: translate3d(20px, 0, 0);
  opacity: 0; }

body.gallery, body.nested_gallery {
  overflow-y: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 100%; }
  body.gallery .page-name-small, body.nested_gallery .page-name-small {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    pointer-events: auto !important;
    top: -2px; }
  body.gallery .breadcrumb-link.bottom, body.nested_gallery .breadcrumb-link.bottom {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease;
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 96; }
    body.gallery .breadcrumb-link.bottom.hidden, body.nested_gallery .breadcrumb-link.bottom.hidden {
      opacity: 0; }
  body.gallery .overview-icon-bottom, body.nested_gallery .overview-icon-bottom {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease;
    display: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 9px;
    right: 100px;
    z-index: 96; }
    body.gallery .overview-icon-bottom.hidden, body.nested_gallery .overview-icon-bottom.hidden {
      opacity: 0;
      pointer-events: none; }
  body.gallery .assets-container, body.nested_gallery .assets-container {
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden; }
    body.gallery .assets-container.is-draggable .asset.img img, body.nested_gallery .assets-container.is-draggable .asset.img img {
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
      user-select: none; }
    body.gallery .assets-container.is-draggable.is-dragging, body.nested_gallery .assets-container.is-draggable.is-dragging {
      cursor: grabbing !important;
      cursor: -moz-grabbing !important;
      cursor: -webkit-grabbing !important; }
  body.gallery .main, body.nested_gallery .main {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease, -webkit-transform 250ms ease;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease, -webkit-transform 250ms ease;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease, transform 250ms ease;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease, transform 250ms ease, -webkit-transform 250ms ease;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1; }
    body.gallery .main .assets-container, body.nested_gallery .main .assets-container {
      display: flex;
      height: 100vh; }
  body.gallery .title-element, body.nested_gallery .title-element {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50vw; }
    body.gallery .title-element .text, body.nested_gallery .title-element .text {
      position: relative;
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 80%; }
    body.gallery .title-element img, body.nested_gallery .title-element img {
      max-width: 600px;
      width: 80%; }
  body.gallery .cover-image, body.nested_gallery .cover-image {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50vw; }
    body.gallery .cover-image.is-landscape img, body.gallery .cover-image.is-square img, body.nested_gallery .cover-image.is-landscape img, body.nested_gallery .cover-image.is-square img {
      max-width: 600px;
      width: 80%; }
    body.gallery .cover-image.is-portrait img, body.nested_gallery .cover-image.is-portrait img {
      max-height: 600px;
      height: 80vh; }
  body.gallery .caption, body.nested_gallery .caption {
    max-width: 80%;
    margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative; }
    body.gallery .caption p, body.nested_gallery .caption p {
      margin: 0; }
    body.gallery .caption p + p, body.nested_gallery .caption p + p {
      margin-top: 1em; }
  body.gallery .asset, body.nested_gallery .asset {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 50vw; }
    body.gallery .asset.is-landscape img, body.gallery .asset.is-square img, body.nested_gallery .asset.is-landscape img, body.nested_gallery .asset.is-square img {
      max-width: 550px;
      width: 80%; }
    body.gallery .asset.is-portrait img, body.nested_gallery .asset.is-portrait img {
      -o-object-fit: contain;
      object-fit: contain;
      max-height: 700px;
      height: 64vh; }
    body.gallery .asset.image img, body.gallery .asset.video img, body.nested_gallery .asset.image img, body.nested_gallery .asset.video img {
      cursor: pointer; }
    body.gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container, body.nested_gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container {
      position: relative;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 600px; }
      body.gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container .vimeo_cont, body.gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container .youtube_cont, body.nested_gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container .vimeo_cont, body.nested_gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container .youtube_cont {
        width: 100%; }
      body.gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container .video-play-icon, body.nested_gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container .video-play-icon {
        -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
        transition: all 250ms ease;
        opacity: 0.9;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -23px;
        margin-left: -23px; }
      body.gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container:hover .video-play-icon, body.nested_gallery .asset.video .video-thumb-container:hover .video-play-icon {
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.08);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.08);
        transform: scale(1.08);
        opacity: 1; }
    body.gallery .asset.text .text-content, body.nested_gallery .asset.text .text-content {
      max-width: 500px;
      padding: 20px;
      position: relative;
      width: 80%; }
  body.gallery .next-nested-page, body.nested_gallery .next-nested-page {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 50vw; }
    body.gallery .next-nested-page .nexted-nested-page-title, body.nested_gallery .next-nested-page .nexted-nested-page-title {
      padding-left: 20px;
      padding-right: 110px; }
      body.gallery .next-nested-page .nexted-nested-page-title .title, body.nested_gallery .next-nested-page .nexted-nested-page-title .title {
        color: #ffffff;
        font-family: "Miller Banner Black", "Miller Banner Black", serif;
        font-size: 19px;
        font-weight: normal; }
      body.gallery .next-nested-page .nexted-nested-page-title .see-more, body.nested_gallery .next-nested-page .nexted-nested-page-title .see-more {
        color: rgba(40, 40, 40, 0.75);
        font-size: 14px; }
    body.gallery .next-nested-page.is-landscape img, body.gallery .next-nested-page.is-square img, body.nested_gallery .next-nested-page.is-landscape img, body.nested_gallery .next-nested-page.is-square img {
      max-width: 600px;
      width: 80%; }
    body.gallery .next-nested-page.is-portrait img, body.nested_gallery .next-nested-page.is-portrait img {
      max-height: 400px;
      height: 80vh; }
    body.gallery .next-nested-page .nexted-nested-page-cover-image, body.nested_gallery .next-nested-page .nexted-nested-page-cover-image {
      transition: opacity 250ms ease;
      transform: translate(100%, -50%);
      opacity: 0.5;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      right: 90px; }
    body.gallery .next-nested-page:hover .nexted-nested-page-cover-image, body.nested_gallery .next-nested-page:hover .nexted-nested-page-cover-image {
      opacity: 1; }
  body.gallery .caption, body.nested_gallery .caption {
    color: #282828;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 2;
    font-family: "Miller Banner Roman", "Miller Banner Roman", serif; }
  body.gallery .gallery-zoom-container, body.nested_gallery .gallery-zoom-container {
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    transition: all 250ms ease;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 97; }
    body.gallery .gallery-zoom-container .vimeo_cont, body.gallery .gallery-zoom-container .youtube_cont, body.nested_gallery .gallery-zoom-container .vimeo_cont, body.nested_gallery .gallery-zoom-container .youtube_cont {
      width: 85vw; }
    body.gallery .gallery-zoom-container img.fit-h, body.nested_gallery .gallery-zoom-container img.fit-h {
      width: 100vw !important;
      height: auto !important; }
    body.gallery .gallery-zoom-container img.fit-v, body.nested_gallery .gallery-zoom-container img.fit-v {
      width: auto !important;
      height: 100vh !important; }
    body.gallery .gallery-zoom-container.landscape img, body.nested_gallery .gallery-zoom-container.landscape img {
      width: auto;
      height: 100vh; }
    body.gallery .gallery-zoom-container.portrait img.is-landscape, body.nested_gallery .gallery-zoom-container.portrait img.is-landscape {
      width: 100vw;
      height: auto; }
    body.gallery .gallery-zoom-container.portrait img.is-portrait, body.nested_gallery .gallery-zoom-container.portrait img.is-portrait {
      width: auto;
      height: 100vh; }
    body.gallery .gallery-zoom-container.active, body.nested_gallery .gallery-zoom-container.active {
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: auto; }
  body.gallery .gallery-counter, body.nested_gallery .gallery-counter {
    -webkit-transition: opacity 250ms ease;
    transition: opacity 250ms ease;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 96; }
    body.gallery .gallery-counter.hidden, body.nested_gallery .gallery-counter.hidden {
      opacity: 0; }
  body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
    -webkit-transition: all 250ms ease;
    transition: all 250ms ease;
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 97; }
    body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .gallery-overview-inner, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .gallery-overview-inner {
      -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      padding: 20px; }
    body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay.active, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay.active {
      opacity: 1;
      pointer-events: auto; }
      body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay.active .gallery-overview-inner, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay.active .gallery-overview-inner {
        overflow-y: auto; }
    body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      min-height: 500px;
      margin: 40px;
      padding: 50px;
      width: calc(33.3333% - 80px); }
      body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content {
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        max-height: 100%;
        width: 100%; }
        body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-left, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-left {
          left: -50px;
          margin-right: auto; }
        body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-right, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-right {
          left: 50px;
          margin-left: auto; }
        body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-top, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-top {
          -ms-flex-item-align: start;
          align-self: flex-start; }
        body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-bottom, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-bottom {
          -ms-flex-item-align: end;
          align-self: flex-end; }
        body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-h-center, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-h-center {
          margin-left: auto;
          margin-right: auto; }
        body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-v-center, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset .overview-asset-content.flush-v-center {
          -webkit-box-align: center;
          -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-self: center; }
      body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset.text .text-content, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .overview-asset.text .text-content {
        background: #ffffff;
        border: 2px solid #282828;
        padding: 50px 30px; }
    body.gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .close-overview, body.nested_gallery .gallery-overview-overlay .close-overview {
      font-size: 4rem;
      color: #282828;
      cursor: pointer;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 20px;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -1rem; }

.is-changing .gallery-counter {
  opacity: 0; }
```

Thanks to whoever takes the time to answer and explain where I did my wrongs :)

Comment: can you add the html content also? check if there is any inline css.

Comment: Not available unfortunately unless I pay double monthly fee to use this template website, smart. I am one step further from only working with custom sites!

Answer (score 0):

You could use web inspection tool to check whether your style is overridden. If so you can append one more class or include another HTML element to your tag and it will override the gallery styles.

Example -

body.gallery.**one_more_class**  .asset.is-landscape img

body.gallery **.wrapper HTML** .asset.is-landscape img